# Custom interpretation of Spark dataframe filtering("where") clauses

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a system that stores data in parquet datasets on s3. Each dataset contains data for a single calendar date.

I want to be able to query for a single date, a set of dates, or a range of dates in plain sql terms.
But instead of needing to fetch all datasets only to discard most of them, I  want to intercept the query interpretation and do the obvious optimisation, based on the date related clauses.

How can one customise spark dataframe/dataest query interpretation? e.g. `select * from X where day = '2018-06-16'` should only fetch the dataset in `/datasets/X/2018-06-16`. The same question applies to using the dataframe DSL, not really attached to using SQL.

3rd party connectors (e.g. Cassandra) must be doing the same kind of intercepting to the query AST. If it is too messy, is using UDFs a viable starting point?

I failed to find relevant documentation but could be due to searching for the wrong terminology

Comment: Reason for downvote please :)

Comment: [Bucketing, Sorting and __Partitioning__](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#bucketing-sorting-and-partitioning) or if you don't mind paying for extra features [Data Skipping Index](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dataskipping-index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you able to change your s3 directories from `/datasets/X/2018-06-16` to `/datasets/X/dt=2018-06-16`. and then create dataset like this

```
val ds = spark.read.parquet("/datasets/X")
```

You can easily query on that

```
ds.where("dt = '2018-06-16'")
```

**or**

```
ds.where("dt >= '2018-06-10' and dt <= '2018-06-16'")
```

It just read only specific dates which you mentioned in your where clause condition

Comment: Great answer, thanks @Kaushal!

For future reference, the documentation for that feature is here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery